# Flashing LED String/Christmas lights to steady on

Tags: microcontroller, led, ac, bridge-rectifier, bypass

I want to bypass the 8 function EK-04 controller( pictured below) and keep lights stay on.
There is a post similar to this but it has the old design.
[Bypassing a multi function Christmas light string controller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/452951/bypassing-a-multi-function-christmas-light-string-controller)
My string lights is of 300 LEDs, input 220-240 volts[image]

I have tried putting the wires directly on the rectifier on another EK-04 (slightly different circuit) LED 120 bulbs 220-240volt but it just makes their resistors very hot.

Just want it to stay on without heating.

Comment: um, just so I can be sure I don't see this incorrectyl: the separation between the right AC 230V cable pad and the leftest of the cables going out to  your LEDs is less than 2mm?! *screams in safety*

Comment: In attempts to find _any_ information about this 8-function EK-04 controller, I came across a document from the Czech Trade Inspection Authority (CTIA) which stated the EK-04 is dangerous. (Search for "130905 dangerous light chains".) I definitely would get rid of that controller and find something else.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Do you think the output wiring is Class 2 and the button can withstand 230 Vac towards the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that you have a transformer between your 230V AC and the PCB! If not, don't use it. In most countries you need a safe insulation when you operate circuits with the voltage from your wall plug. For example, a double cable insulation is mandatory. But it looks as if this string is not correctly isolated. That's why we suggest to protect yourself and your beloved. *(However, I don't know how the complete string looks like. Chances are that its manufacturer does not care about your health.)*

However, if you connect the marked pads, all LEDs should light up constantly. Do **not** create a short to the circuit path between the leftmost pad and the next pad. This path is the other pole of the rectified supply voltage. A short circuit will blow up the rectifier lightning fast, and it will release the "magic smoke" that operates all such components, as we all know.

The small blocks marked by "406" are transistors that switch the LED strings. By the patch, you bridge the transistors.

[image: Patch]

Comment: "Please make sure that you have a transformer between your 230V AC and the PCB!" What kind of transformer? My country runs on 220v. "Do not create a short to the circuit path between the leftmost pad and the next pad." Can you please elaborate on that. And I did connect all the marked pads and it did work but while it was on I accidentally touched 154 resistor with tester and it deformed from the top it works nonetheless. Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: Whoo, you approached this circuit while it was on? How lucky you are that you're still alive. However, if the resistor is deformed, chances are that it and the integrated circuit hidden in the black blob are damaged now. But you didn't want to use it any more...

Comment: @m_kf2 if it's working, you haven't shorted it! The connection in orange goes from the negative (-) pin of the MB10F to the 4 pads shown, but not touching the circuit board track connected to the positive (+) pin.  Beware all the led strings are connected to live mains voltage!

Comment: @the busybee Yes I wont use that one. I am going to put 10 of these as Christmas decorations, any other safety measures etc that I should be aware of. Thank you

Comment: @m_kf2 You might want to edit your question and provide an image where the first LEDs can be seen and how they are connected to the PCB, so we can see what's actually there. As I wrote, many countries demand a double insulation.